# Adding an Observer to WKWebView for URL Change Detection

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, observers

How would I go about adding an observer/listener for my WKWebView and detecting if the URL has changed? All of the preset WKWebView functions don't seem to detect window.location and window.hash changes, even though the URL is changing.

Comment: WKWebView has the didFinish method.

Comment: Right, but as mentioned, it doesn't always get fired if the content of the WKWebView is using window.location.hash methods. In my case, every URL change doesn't set off a single WKWebView method.